# React - Using Regex for highlighting text inside of dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Not working reliably

Tags: regex, reactjs, replace, highlight

The goal is to highlight text parts (strings) inside of a dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Therefore I try to match the desired text part inside of the html, and wrap it in a "span" with appropriate styling. I am using the following code that works for certain texts (html) flawlessy, but for certain texts not at all. Please find a working an a not working example below.

My question is: Why is the regex failing in some cases and working in others? Even though in all cases the text ("quote") is there.

**Highlighting Component JSX:**

```
import React from "react";



class HighlightQuote extends React.Component {
  render = () => {

    //zitat is for getting rid of any quotation marks in the beginning or end.
    var zitat = this.props.quotes.map(x => x.replace(/^[“”"’()]+|[“”"’()]+$/g, ""));

    if (this.props.quotes.length === 0) {
      var highlightedHtml = this.props.newcontent

    }
    else {
      var zitat = this.props.quotes.map(x => x.replace(/^[“”"’()]+|[“”"’()]+$/g, ""));
      const regex = new RegExp(`(${zitat.join('|')})`, 'g');
      var highlightedHtml = this.props.content.replace(
          regex,
          '<span class="hl">$1</span>'
        );
       console.log ('highlightedHtml:');
       console.log (highlightedHtml);
    }


    return (
        <div className="reader" ref="test" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: highlightedHtml }} />

    );
  };
}

export default HighlightQuote;
```

**Working example (console.log ('highlighted html')**

```
<div class="post" id="post-17660">
  <p class="postcontents">
    <article>
      <div class="post-inside">
        <p>One of the things I have disliked the most about the crypto sector is the idea that people should &#x201C;hodl&#x201D; or &#x201C;hold on for dear life.&#x201D;</p>
        <p>I have written many times here at AVC that one should take profits when they are available and diversify an investment portfolio.</p>
        <p><span class="hl">The idea that an investor should hold on no matter what has always seemed ridiculous to me.</span></p>
        <p>Now, the crypto markets are in the eighth month of a long and painful bear market and we are starting to see some signs of capitulation, particularly in the assets that went up the most last year.</p>
        <p>Whether this is the long-awaited&#xA0;capitulation of the HODL crowd or not, I can&#x2019;t say.</p>
        <p>But capitulation would be a good thing for the crypto markets, releasing assets into the market that until now have been locked up by long-term&#xA0;holders.</p>
        <p><span class="hl">Until then it is hard to get excited about buying anything in crypto.</span></p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </p>
</div>
```

Quotes that are highlighted as expected:

```
"The idea that an investor should hold on no matter what has always seemed ridiculous to me."

"Until then it is hard to get excited about buying anything in crypto."
```

**Failing example (console.log ('highlighted html')**

```
<div><article id="story" class="Story-story--2QyGh css-1j0ipd9"><header class="css-1qcpy3f e345g291"><p class="css-1789nl8 etcg8100"><a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.nytimes.com/column/new-sentences">New Sentences</a></p><div class="css-30n6iy e345g290"><div class="css-acwcvw"></div></div><figure class="ResponsiveMedia-media--32g1o ResponsiveMedia-sizeSmall--3092U ResponsiveMedia-layoutVertical--1pg1o ResponsiveMedia-sizeSmallNoCaption--n--T0 css-1hzd7ei"><figcaption class="css-pplcdj ResponsiveMedia-caption--1dUVu"></figcaption></figure></header><div class="css-18sbwfn StoryBodyCompanionColumn"><div class="css-1h6whtw"><p class="css-1i0edl6 e2kc3sl0"><em class="css-2fg4z9 ehxkw330">&#x2014; From Keith Gessen&#x2019;s second novel, &#x201C;A Terrible Country&#x201D; (Viking, 2018, Page 4). Gessen is also the author of &#x201C;All the Sad Young Literary Men&#x201D; and a founding editor of the journal n+1.</em></p><p class="css-1i0edl6 e2kc3sl0">All authors have signature sentence structures &#x2014; deep expressive grooves that their minds instinctively find and follow. (That previous sentence is one of mine: a simple declaration that leaps, after the break of a long dash, into an elaborate restatement.)</p><p class="css-1i0edl6 e2kc3sl0">Here is one of Keith Gessen&#x2019;s:</p><p class="css-1i0edl6 e2kc3sl0">&#x201C;As for me, I wasn&#x2019;t really an idiot. But neither was I not an idiot.&#x201D;</p><p class="css-1i0edl6 e2kc3sl0">&#x201C;I hadn&#x2019;t been yelling, I didn&#x2019;t think. But I hadn&#x2019;t not been yelling either.&#x201D;</p><p class="css-1i0edl6 e2kc3sl0">&#x201C;Cute cafes were not the problem, but they were also not, as I&#x2019;d once apparently thought, the opposite of the problem.&#x201D;</p></div><aside class="css-14jsv4e"><span></span></aside></div><div class="css-18sbwfn StoryBodyCompanionColumn"><div class="css-1h6whtw"><p class="css-1i0edl6 e2kc3sl0">Sentence structures are not simply sentence structures, of course &#x2014; they are miniature philosophies. Hemingway, with his blunt verbal bullets, is making a huge claim about the nature of the world. So is James Joyce, with his collages and frippery. So are Nikki Giovanni and Samuel Delany and Ursula K. Le Guin and John McPhee and Missy Elliott and Dr. Seuss and anyone else who converts thoughts into prose.</p><p class="css-1i0edl6 e2kc3sl0">Likewise, Keith Gessen&#x2019;s signature sentence structure &#x2014; &#x201C;not X, but also not not X&#x201D; &#x2014; suggests an entire worldview. It is a universe of in-betweenness, in which the most basic facts of life, the things we absolutely expect to understand, spill and scatter like toast crumbs into the gaps between the floorboards. It is a world of embarrassingly trivial category errors. The sentences above come from Gessen&#x2019;s new novel, &#x201C;A Terrible Country,&#x201D; the story of a 30-something American man who goes to Russia to care for his elderly grandmother. He falls into the gaps between huge concepts: youth and age, purpose and purposelessness, progress and stasis. He is not Russian but also not not Russian, not smart but also not not smart, not heroic but also not not heroic. Such is the way of the world. No matter how much we try, none of us is ever only one thing. None of us is ever pure.</p></div><aside class="css-14jsv4e"><span></span></aside></div><div class="bottom-of-article"><div class="css-k8fkhk"><p>Sam Anderson is a staff writer for the magazine.</p> <p><i>Sign up for </i><a href="http://www.nytimes.com/newsletters/magazine"><i>our newsletter</i></a><i> to get the best of The New York Times Magazine delivered to your inbox every week.</i></p></div><div class="css-3glrhn">A version of this article appears in print on , on Page 11 of the Sunday Magazine with the headline: From Keith Gessen&#x2019;s &#x2018;A Terrible Country&#x2019;<span>. <a href="http://www.nytreprints.com/">Order Reprints</a> | <a href="http://www.nytimes.com/pages/todayspaper/index.html">Today&#x2019;s Paper</a> | <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/subscriptions/Multiproduct/lp8HYKU.html?campaignId=48JQY">Subscribe</a></span></div></div><span></span></article></div>
```

The quote that should be highlighted:

```
"Sentence structures are not simply sentence structures, of course — they are miniature philosophies"
```

Comment: What is inside `zitat`?

Comment: If I get ir right, you have an array of phrases and this `this.props.quotes.map(...)` is for removing any starting/ending parenthesis, or any kind of quote. Is this part working as you expect? Then there's the next regex that I believe you use to wrap the spans. Is that last regex working? Which part needs to be fixed?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `zitat` is just the quote (`this.props.quotes`) without any quotation marks.

Comment: @Julio Yes, you are right, the first part is just for cleaning the quotation marks. The following regex is for wrapping the quotes with the spans. - Yes, the last regex is working for some texts, and not for others. See the two examples above. That's the "challenge" / question. I have no clue, why and how the html can have any impact on the regex at all. Why does it not work sometimes, even though the quote is to 100% there.

Comment: Try `const regex = new RegExp(\`(${zitat.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|')})\`, 'g');`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks so much for looking into this. I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately didn't work. As I looked into some console logs though I saw that most likely the reason for the failing Regex lies in "entity references". In the failing example above the quote includes a "—" character that in the html is written as &#x2014; Wondering now if there is some easy way to translate this in html code without entity references... - Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the failing regex matches were html entities. Some of the parsed texts inside of the dangerouslySetInnerHTML used entity references. In the failing example above the quote includes a "—" character that in the html is decoded as `&#x2014;` .

In order to get rid of the html entities I used the "he" library https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he a robust HTML entity encoder/decoder written in JavaScript.

```
 var contentDecoded = he.decode(this.props.content);

 var highlightedHtml = contentDecoded.replace(
    regex,
    '<span class="annotator-hl">$1</span>'
 );
```